# Javascript, Jquery: get element by two attr?

Tags: javascript, jquery

HTML:

```
<form id="form_filter" action="{{ Request::fullUrl() }}" method="post">
<input type="checkbox" name="shape[]" value="Aviator">
<input type="checkbox" name="shape[]" value="Round">
<input type="checkbox" name="shape[]" value="Oval">
</form>
```

I need get element by [name] and [value] as:

```
$('#form_filter input[name=shape][value=Round]').prop('checked', true);
```

Please help!

Comment: `[name^=shape]`

Comment: to extend Mohamed's comment - your input name isn't shape, it's shape[]

Comment: @KunalMukherjee you should not do edits to answer the question or change the code - now the question doesn't make sense as the code works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your have missed `[]` in the name value, it should be `name="shape[]"`

```js
$('#form_filter input[name="shape[]"][value=Round]').prop('checked', true);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form_filter" action="{{ Request::fullUrl() }}" method="post">
<input type="checkbox" name="shape[]" value="Aviator">
<input type="checkbox" name="shape[]" value="Round">
<input type="checkbox" name="shape[]" value="Oval">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should just use quotes inside the selector, ie:

```
$('#form_filter input[name="shape[]"][value="Round"]').length === 1 // true
```

Or:

```
$('#form_filter input[name="shape[]"][value="Round"]').prop('checked', true); // checks your specific checkbox
```

[jQuery docs on equals selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) also state the following:

> attribute: An attribute name.
>
> value: An attribute value. Can be either a valid identifier or a
>   *quoted string*.

---

Test on the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1hrbfmqc/).